# Javascript not highlighting menu when accessing the website for the firsttime

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

Here is my problem, i have a list of menu items not using runat="server", so my default page have a url like localhost/Default.aspx, if i run it in visual studio, my javascript will find my current page, which is "Default.aspx" and highlight the current menu item, everything works perfectly at this point.

Now if i publish my website using ftp, the first time i go on that site, the site will have the url localhost, without the Default.aspx at the end, now my javascript will not find "Default.aspx" in my page and will instead return "", so my menu item is not highlighted. If i click on homepage in my menu, the url becomes localhost/Default.aspx, and the menu becomes highlighted.

So is there a way to alter my javascript so the first time i click on that site, it will still highlight my menu even though my url doesn't contain "Default.aspx" at the end?

Here is my javascript"

```
$(function () {
   var url = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
   $('[href$="' + url + '"]').parent("li").addClass("current_page_item");
});
```

As you can see, if i use

```
<a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a>
```

for my homepage, the

```
lastIndexOf("/")
```

in my javascript will always return me blank, and so nothing is highlighted, i know where the problem is, but cannot figure out a way to fix it

Thanks

html:

1.main menu

```
<div id="menu" class="container">
        <ul>
            <li class="current_page_item"><a runat="server" href="~/" accesskey="1" title="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="Softcare/SoftcareHome.aspx" accesskey="2" title="">Softcare</a></li>
            <li><a href="Softlearn/SoftlearnHome.aspx" accesskey="2" title="">Softlearn</a></li>
            <li><a href="Software/SoftwareHome.aspx" accesskey="2" title="">Software</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

2.sidemenu

```
<div id="sidemenu">
        <div class="section-title">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="submenutitle" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li><a runat="server" href="~/" accesskey="1" title="">Home</a></li>
        </ul>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('[href$="' + ((url == "")?"~/":url) + '"]').parent("li").addClass("current_page_item");
```

Comment: Thanks Maverick, however it is still not highlighting, the parent of url "~/" is nothing

Comment: can you post html of your menu

Comment: i added it in my question

Comment: I changed homepage and sidemenu to runat="server" href="~/" just to reflect your suggestion

Comment: can you try alert(url), to see what's coming. See this http://jsfiddle.net/bdggP/

Comment: using my original javascript, the alert returns Default.aspx and when setting href to "~/", the alert returns blank

Comment: in that case, you will have to show your full URLs, as u can see my fiddlem blank url selectes the HOME

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention, there is a class defined in my menu list for Homepage, if you remove that class, javascript will not highlight it, because it is returning a blank url

Comment: I can think a solution, changing lastindex of url " " to "Default.aspx" will do the trick, but don't know how to implement it, so:    `If(url=="") {url=="Default.aspx" $('[href$="' + url + '"]').parent("li").addClass("current_page_item");}`

Comment: $('[href$="' + ((url == "")?"Default.aspx":url) + '"]')

Comment: Thanks Maverick, i wasn't thinking this through enough, changing url won't work, i need to somehow change the relative path to absolute path and then do work to it...the whole thing is too much of a struggle, might have to change my javascript code all together...Thanks for the help..